# Permutation with repetition and condition, generalized

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a generalized version of ([Permutation with repetition and condition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207306/permutation-with-repetition-and-condition)). Suppose we have a set of integers $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ to fit in $k (k\geq n)$ slots, such that every $I\in S$ appears *at least once*. Then how many number of permutation schemes are there?

For example, suppose we have $S=\{1,2\}$ and $k=3$ then

```
1,2,1
1,2,2
2,1,2
2,1,1
1,1,2
2,2,1
```

*My Attempt:*
Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of schemes.
$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{k\choose i}f(n-1,k-i)$ with corresponding boundaries such as $f(1,k)=1, f(n,n)=n! , f(a,b)=0 [\textbf{if}\quad b<a]$.

Does this recursion looks correct? Or, more importantly, any closed-form representation of $f(n,k)$?

---

${k\choose n}n!n^{k-n}$ is not correct. Don't bother try LOL.